# UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp - how to distinguish between portrait and landscape?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, landscape-portrait, uideviceorientation

I'm trying to find out if the device is in portrait or landscape mode. My code works quite well if the device is not facing up. If it does face up (and orientation == 5), it won't distinguish between portrait and landscape. Is there anyway to determine the "orientation" in terms of landscape / portrait if the UIDeviceOrientation is FaceUp?

My code:

```
UIDeviceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

NSLog(@"orientation: %d", interfaceOrientation);

if (interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)) {
    NSLog(@"LANDSCAPE!!!");
}

if (interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)) {
    NSLog(@"PORTRAIT!!!");
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You should not confuse `UIDeviceOrientation` and `UIInterfaceOrientation`, they are different but related as shown by their declaration

```
typedef enum {
   UIDeviceOrientationUnknown,
   UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
   UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
   UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft,
   UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
   UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp,
   UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown
} UIDeviceOrientation;

typedef enum {
   UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait           = UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
   UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown = UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
   UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft      = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
   UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight     = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft
} UIInterfaceOrientation;
```

`UIDeviceOrientation` tells you what the orientation of the device is. `UIInterfaceOrientation` tells you what the orientation of your interface is, and is used by `UIViewController`. `UIInterfaceOrientation` will clearly be either portrait or landscape, whereas `UIDeviceOrientation` can have ambiguous values (`UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp`, `UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown`, `UIDeviceOrientationUnknown`).

In any case you should not attempt to determine the orientation of a UIViewController with `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]`, as no matter what the device orientation is the `UIViewController interfaceOrientation` property can be different (for example if your app does not rotate to landscape at all `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` can be `UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft` while `viewController.interfaceOrientation` can be `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait`).

**Update:**
As of iOS 8.0, `[UIViewController interfaceOrientation]` is deprecated. An alternative offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30082974/2396171) is `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]`. This also returns `UIInterfaceOrientation`.

Answer (score 5):

I make this code skeleton for dealing with wanted & unwanted devices orientations, in my case i want to ignore the UIDeviceOrientationUnknown, UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp and UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown, caching the last allowed orientation. This code deals with iPhone and iPad devices and can be useful for you.

```
- (void)modXibFromRotation {

    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    NSString *device = [[UIDevice currentDevice]localizedModel];
    UIInterfaceOrientation cachedOrientation = [self interfaceOrientation];

    if ([device isEqualToString:@"iPad"]) {

        if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationUnknown || 
            orientation == UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp || 
            orientation == UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown) {

                orientation = (UIDeviceOrientation)cachedOrientation;
        }

        if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

            /* Your code */
        }

        if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {

            /* Your code */     
        }
    }

    if ([device isEqualToString:@"iPhone"] || [device isEqualToString:@"iPod"]) {

        if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationUnknown || 
        orientation == UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp || 
        orientation == UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown) {

            orientation = (UIDeviceOrientation)cachedOrientation;
        }

        if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

             /* Your code */
        }

        if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {

            /* Your code */
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS13 use

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation;
if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
    orientation = self.window.windowScene.interfaceOrientation;
} else {
    orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
}
```