# Detect device orientation in Init function

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, landscape-portrait

I am detecting the device orientation with these lines of code:

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isPortrait.boolValue
UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape.boolValue
```

And I detect check if it's an iPad with this code:

```
userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad
```

I used this code in `commonInit()` function which is called in the `Init()` function. When I execute my code on iPad the two first lines return both `false` which is not correct, one of them should be `true`. The third line is working fine.

If I use the code in other functions, such as `supportedInterfaceOrientations()`, it works fine. Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: `init()`... `init()`..., whose `init()` method are we talking about?

Comment: The init() methode of the classe where I am trying to use the lines of code. I want to inantiate the class with values dependent of the orientation of the iPad

Comment: @holex was asking for the *type* of the class...is it a UIViewController? Has the App fully initialized and told the AppDelegate it's ready before this class is constructed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably neglecting this documentation:

> You also use the UIDevice instance to detect changes in the device’s
>   characteristics, such as physical orientation. You get the current
>   orientation using the orientation property or receive change
>   notifications by registering for the
>   UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification notification. **Before using
>   either of these techniques to get orientation data, you must enable
>   data delivery using the beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications
>   method**. When you no longer need to track the device orientation, call
>   the endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications method to disable the
>   delivery of notifications.

Also, this is a 3-D orientation. You probably don't want that. What is the *actual* value of simply the `orientation` property? See:

```
enum UIDeviceOrientation : Int {
    case Unknown
    case Portrait
    case PortraitUpsideDown
    case LandscapeLeft
    case LandscapeRight
    case FaceUp
    case FaceDown }
```

Probably what you really want is here:
["interfaceOrientation" is deprecated in iOS 8, How to change this method Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28787165/interfaceorientation-is-deprecated-in-ios-8-how-to-change-this-method-objecti)

> Sometimes TraitCollections doesn't fill all your design needs. For
>   those cases, Apple recommends to compare view's bounds :
>
> if view.bounds.size.width > view.bounds.size.height {
>       // ... }